# How to convert HTML to PDF using weasyprint python

Tags: python, flask

I am trying pdf generate using `weasyprint` but I could not able

```
from weasyprint import HTML
def makepdf(html):
"""Generate a PDF file from a string of HTML."""
htmldoc = HTML(string=html, base_url="")
return htmldoc.write_pdf()
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this?  Exactly?

Comment: Sir, I am trying above the code. But it not work. I want to convert HTML to  pdf file generate using  flask.

Comment: did you run in console to see error message? Did you use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variable? it is called "print debuging". Maybe this function is never executed.

Comment: "But it not work" is of no use at all.  What happened?  Exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this?

```
 from weasyprint import HTML
 HTML('path_of_html').write_pdf('path_of_pdf')
```

Comment: In my case  , I got error in  "from weasyprint import HTML"  .

Comment: @GanesanJ Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68053259/edit) your question to **post these errors** that you get. It is really difficult for people to help you if you don't describe **exactly** what is happening. "*I got error*" and "*it now work*" are not helpful.

Comment: then it should be something wrong when you install it. Do you follow this ?https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html  **Please note Python, cairo, Pango and GDK-PixBuf need to be installed separately.**

Comment: AttributeError: function/symbol 'pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions' not found in library 'libpango-1.0.so.0': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions